# linux mint 19.2 Failed to fetch Insomnia Repository

Tags: insomnia, linux-mint-19

I want to downgrade my php version from 8 to 7.4
so I add php repo `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
but when I run  `sudo apt update` I got error from Insomnia repo

```
Err:16 https://dl.bintray.com/getinsomnia/Insomnia  InRelease                                     
  403  Forbidden [IP: 52.35.132.179 443]
Reading package lists... Done                       
E: Failed to fetch https://dl.bintray.com/getinsomnia/Insomnia/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 52.35.132.179 443]
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/getinsomnia/Insomnia  InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I thanks for anyone can help me, because I am still newbie in linux

Comment: This will solve your problem https://insomnia.rest/blog/new-insomnia-apt-repository

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the Software & Updates then go to Other software tab and uncheck the APT.

[image]

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem, just disables access to the repo

Comment: This will solve your problem
https://insomnia.rest/blog/new-insomnia-apt-repository